# Taking advantage of linearity of integration in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, integration

I want to evaluate an integral of form given below

$$\int\limits_\alpha^\beta (f(x) + g(x) + h(x) + ...) dx$$

When I give it to Mathematica it takes forever to evaluate. But if I give it in this form

$$\int\limits_\alpha^\beta f(x)dx + \int\limits_\alpha^\beta g(x)dx + \int\limits_\alpha^\beta h(x)dx + ...$$

It takes comparatively lesser time.

According to [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/TheMathematicaBook/PrinciplesOfMathematica/Patterns/2.3.14.html) it can be defined as

```
integrate[y_ + z_, x_] :=
integrate[y, x] + integrate[z, x]
```

for two variables. 
But I want to be able to do this for arbitrary number of variables. How to is the question.

Comment: Perhaps you could list your functions as $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ instead of $f(x), g(x), \ldots$ and set mathematica up to read it as $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f_i(x) dx$? I don't have the mathematica skill to tell you the exact code, though.

Comment: I got it `integrate[y_ + z_, x_] := integrate[y, x] + integrate[z, x]` is recursively defined. It takes care of arbitrary summation number of functions. Now my problem is that  `integrate` does not `Integrate`.

Comment: I tried `integrate := Integrate` and wow!! it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed this question, so please forgive the (very) late reply.

If you want a function that will automatically split across addition, like you've tried to define, I'd do this

```
Clear[integrate]
integrate[a_Plus, x_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
  integrate[#, x, opts]& /@ a
```

which with input

```
integrate[a + b + c, {x, 0, 5}]
```

gives

```
integrate[a, {x, 0, 5}] + integrate[b, {x, 0, 5}] 
  + integrate[c, {x, 0, 5}]
```

Then, you can define

```
integrate[a_, x_, opts:OptionsPattern[]]:= Integrate[a, x, opts]
```

to map it back to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

For 
$$\int\limits_\alpha^\beta (f(x) + g(x) + h(x) + ...) dx$$

```
  In[1]:=  f[x_]:= your definition 
  In[2]:=  g[x_]:= your definition
  In[3]:=  h[x_]:= your definition
  In[4]:=  F={f[x],g[x],h[x]}
  In[5]:=  Sum[Integrate[F[[i]],{x,a,b}], {i, 1, 3}]
```

This does what you want, i.e integrates the $f,g,h\cdots$ and then adds them, rather than adding and then integrating. Tested on Mathematica 7

Comment: Problem is I get output in the form of $f(x)+g(x)+h(x)+...$ after doing a lot many operations, say after expanding something. I am not defining the functions.

Comment: @MachineCharmer is that perhaps because you have used the lower case `i` for `Integrate` in your question. Mathematica is case sensitive.

Comment: i.e `integrate[x,y]` just echos the same expression while `Integrate[x,y]` returns `xy` Maybe that is why you are getting the sums

Comment: @kuch nahi: I think he means that he has arbitrary number of terms in his sum. You could generalize this answer by automatically splitting the integrand with `F = Apply[List, q[x]]` where `g[x] = f[x] + g[x] + ...` (untested). Edit: I missed that a recursive solution was found in the other comments.